# Meteor allow deny functions?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my application i am using a collection called **Polls_Coll**

here is my allow function

```
Polls_Coll.allow({
            insert:function(){
                    return true;
                    },
            update:function(userId, doc, fields, modifier){
                    return (doc.owner===userId);
                    },
            remove:function(){
                return true;
            }
        });
```

i inserted a document after log-in to  my account

when i try to update that document values from client side

```
var option_data=Polls_Coll.findOne({_id:this._id}).option2[0].pd;
            var u_name=Meteor.user().profile.name;
            Polls_Coll.update({_id:this._id,"option2.pd":option_data},{$push:{"option2.$.ids":u_name}});
```

it is showing error that `untrusted code may update using id only`  but it is working when i try to insert it from server side
Here is how i inserted document into collection

```
Polls_Coll.insert({question: quest,
                    option1:[{pd:op1,ids:[]}],
                    option2:[{pd:op2,ids:[]}],
                    option3:[{pd:op3,ids:[]}],
                    option4:[{pd:op4,ids:[]}]
                    });
```

why the values are not updating from client side.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#update) section in the docs:

> Untrusted code includes client-side code such as event handlers and a browser's JavaScript console.
>
> Untrusted code can only modify a single document at once, specified by its _id.

So, I believe, the only selector allowed is an `_id`. You can achieve the same result with the `$set` operator with something like:

```js
var poll = Polls_Coll.findOne({_id: this._id});
poll.option2[0].ids.push(Meteor.user().profile.name);
Polls_Coll.update({_id: this._id}, {$set: {option2: poll.option2}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Meteor handles `update()` differenty for trusted code ( on the server ) than it does for untrusted code ( on the client ).

> Untrusted code can only modify a single document at once, specified by its _id. - from http://docs.meteor.com/#update

Any other criteria inside of the `update()` selector would allow you to learn what is in the db object by trying multiple selectors, so the development group has eliminated this possibility.  If you need to verify that other criteria are met before updating then check this with `findOne()`.